# JBoss hibernate error in inserting data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, wildfly, mariadb

I configured a data source and use it in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="myds">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/BBDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>         
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

I tested it and it shows the connection was successful:

> http://localhost:9990/console

In my Web application, I have an import.sql for initial loading to database:

```
insert into Member (id, name, email, phone_number) values (0, 'John Smith', 'john.smith@mailinator.com', '2125551212')
```

I am using Wildfly server, and I tried to launch my application, but received this error message. It seems it can't load the initial Member record.

```
01:57:49,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver (version 2.0)
01:57:49,831 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: bword.war
01:57:49,854 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.2.6 (Final)
01:57:49,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = bword.war_org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver_2_0
01:57:49,872 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment bword.war
01:57:49,970 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'bword.war#myds'
01:57:50,022 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
01:57:50,109 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
01:57:50,196 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
01:57:50,410 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
01:57:50,416 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists Member
01:57:50,416 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,417 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
01:57:50,417 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,417 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table Member (id bigint not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(25) not null, phone_number varchar(12) not null, primary key (id))
01:57:50,417 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Member add constraint UK_9qv6yhjqm8iafto8qk452gx8h  unique (email)
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table hibernate_sequence ( next_val bigint )
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
01:57:50,418 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,419 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: insert into Member (id, name, email, phone_number) values (0, 'John Smith', 'john.smith@mailinator.com', '2125551212')
01:57:50,419 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) No database selected
01:57:50,419 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

I have a specific question:

1) The data source name is "BBDS". Should I create the database name "BBDS" in my MySql (MariaDB) before I run the application? I thought the database and tables will be automatically created and destroyed due to

2) "No database selected", where to specify the database?

Edited:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/BBDS" pool-name="BBDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mariadb-java-client-1.3.2.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>testUser</user-name>
                        <password>testPass</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database will not be created automatically for you with such configuration. The BombwordDS datasource has to be configured in wildfly before you deploy this application and it should reference an existing database.

If you don't care about persisting your data for now, and just want to test your application / schema, you could also use Wildfly included ExampleDS which uses H2 in-memory database.

Comment: I want to set up my own database. The ExampleDS works fine. I created an empty database BombwordDS, but still received the same error. Now to get rid of the "No database selected" issue?

Comment: Could you share your datasource configuration?

Comment: Remi, please see my data source configuration in standalone.xml. The datasource connects fine when I test in in the wildfly management console.

Comment: I missed the BombwordDS in the URL connection. corrected and it works. Thanks.